# WCF Data Service Exception

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I am working on C#.Net with <strike>ADO.NET Dataservice</strike> WCF Data Services.

I try to update one record to relational table, when I reach `context.SetLink()` I am getting `exception("The context is not currently tracking the entity")`. I don't know how to solve this problem. My code is specified below.

```
LogNote dbLogNote =logNote;
LogSubSession dbLogSubSession = (from p in context.LogSubSession
                                 where p.UID == logNote.SubSessionId
                                 select p).First<LogSubSession>()
                                 as LogSubSession;
context.AddToLogNote(dbLogNote);
dbLogNote.LogSubSession = dbLogSubSession;
context.SetLink(dbLogNote, "LogSubSession", dbLogSubSession);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here `LogSubSession` is a primary table and `LogNote` is a foreign table. I am updating data into foreign table based on primary key table.

Thanks

Comment: ADO.NET Data Services were renamed WCF Data Services several months ago. Also: more information please! Is this Linq-to-SQL as the database layer, or Linq-to-Entities?

Answer (score 0):

Try using AttachLink() to let the entity know to start tracking the link.